# Работа с txt файлом

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт брал из txt файла первую строку, затем записывал содержимое этой строки в какую-нибудь переменную (допустим, $stroka), затем заходил на какой-нибудь сайт (допустим, 'http://site.ru/?'.$stroka) и если на этом сайте был бы текст "yes", то скрипт бы удалял эту строку из txt файла, в ином случае он бы проверял вторую строку, третью, четвертую и так пока они не закончатся?

Comment: Вопрос из разряда напишите мне полностью скрипт :)  Здесь же совсем простые функции нужны, информации по которым в интернете уйма :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file_name = "fileName.txt"; // Путь до файла откуда читать строки

if ($lines = @file($file_name))
{
    foreach($lines as $key => $line)
    {
        if (@file_get_contents('http://site.ru/?'.rtrim($line)) === 'yes')
        {
            unset($lines[$key]);
            file_put_contents($file_name, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Дополнение: я бы использовал функцию file для разбивки файла по строкам. =)

Comment: Хм, точно, совсем про нее забыл :)

Comment: конечный символ переноса строки придется чистить

Comment: Разумеется надо, думаешь зачем нужен rtrim?

Answer (score 3):

1. Открываем файл функцией fopen();
2. Все содержимое присваиваем переменной $file_content;
3. Делим содержимое по символу переноса строки( "rn" ) функцией explode(). Результат заносим в массив $file_array;
4. В цикле перебираем массив $file_array;
5. В каждой итерации:
   5.1. Функцией file_get_contents() получаем содержимое ресурса "http://site.net/?" . $file_array[$i];
   5.2. Проверяем. Если не "yes", то $array[] = $file_array[$i];
6. Очищаем наш текстовый файл
7. В цикле перебираем массив $array;
8. В каждой итерации:
   8.1. Записываем строку $array[i] в файл допутсим функцией fwrite();
9. Закрываем файл